# Pipe out of a command or script to another python script

Tags: python, windows, pipe

I'm relatively to to python and I'm trying to write a python script to which one can pipe the output of a command or another script.

```
example command | python_sript.py
```

In python script I'll basically analyze the output of command and save it to file.

I thought I'll be able to do this with redirecting sys.stdin to subprocess.PIPE, but it didn't work.

```
sys.stdin = subprocess.PIPE
```

Can some one please suggest how should I approach this?

Also what would happen if command or script pipes data at faster rate then what python script can process.

Note: When I use this script

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readline()
print(data)
```

I get this

```
D:\>echo "test" | tee.py
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Profiles\Administrator\My Documents\Workspace\tee.py", line 3, in <mo
dule>
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

and when I use this

```
import sys
data = input()
print(data)
```

I get this

```
D:\>echo "test" | tee.py
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Profiles\Administrator\My Documents\Workspace\tee.py", line 3, in <mo
dule>
    data = input()
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

Comment: In your edit it looks like you have done something silly with `sys.stdin`. Try `sys.__stdin__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On (old) Windows when you use pipes you need to call python scripts using `python` executable by default [due to NT redirection bug](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable):

```
D:\> echo "test" | python tee.py
```

After that `sys.stdin`, `raw_input()`, `fileinput.input()` should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit unclear on how pipes work. They are handled by the OS, not the individual programs -- so if you write a Python script designed to take input data from a pipe, it should just read `stdin` as normal and the redirection will be handled for you. The data will be consumed as fast as they are generated; if the script consumes data more slowly than they are generated then they will be stored in a buffer.

Or are you trying to communicate between *two* Python scripts? If so there are better ways than through `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Which better ways would you recommend?

Comment: @Thomas: 1) Put the data handler in a module and import it. 2) Spawn a separate process and pipe it.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 (reading from a pipe) has been answered by others: Just read stdin in python_script.py. The OS handles the redirection through pipes.

Question 2 (writing/reading speed) has also been answered: OS pipes are buffered, so nothing to be concerned about here.

Question 3 (the stack traces): Your first program runs fine with me. - Are you really giving the whole code here?

As for subprocess.PIPE: You really only want to use this, if you **start a new command from within your running Python script**, so you can communicate with the child process. As you are not doing this, it is of no use to you. Pipes on the shell level don't constitute parent-child processes.

Comment: About the stack trace, first program is not working for me. Is sys.stdin.readline() not supported under Python 3.1? And yes these are the complete programs.